# PowerPoint vba - Custom Ribbon/group does not refresh when screen is empty

Tags: vba, powerpoint, office-addins, ribbonx, powerpoint-addins

I have three templates and for using these templates I am making an add-in with a custom Ribbon Tab. What I would like, is as follows:
When PowerPoint is opened, and the add-in is loaded, the user only sees three buttons on the custom Tab (= the three templates) which can be used to start a new presentation.
When template A is choosen to make a new presentation, group 1 gets visible on the custom Ribbon Tab. When the presentation is closed, the group disappears. And this also for 2 and 3. They are never visible all together.

I think I’m almost there, but the Ribbon does not refresh when there is no presentation already open (empty PPT screen) and I start a new one (or open one) via my menu. Then my template-depended group does not appear in the Ribbon.

XML:

```
<customUI onLoad="RibbonOnLoad"  …>

<group id="MyCustomGroup1" label="Name" getVisible="GetVisible" tag="MyPersonalGroup1"
And there I've added some custom buttons.
```

I also made "MyPersonalGroup2" and "MypersonalGroup3" like this.

VBA what I have now

```
Dim Rib As IRibbonUI
Dim MyTag As String

'Callback for customUI.onLoad
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub getVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
Select Case control.Tag
    Case "MyPersonalGroup1"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateA")
    Case "MyPersonalGroup2"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateB")
    Case "MyPersonalGroup3"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateC")
End Select
End Sub
```

Class module ApplicationEventClass:

```
Public WithEvents PPTEvent As Application

Private Sub PPTEvent_WindowSelectionChange(ByVal Sel As Selection)
    MyTag = Tag
    If Rib Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, restart your presentation"
    Else
        Rib.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub
```

I repeated this code for 'PPTEvent_AfterNewPresentation' 'PPTEvent_AfterPresentationOpen' 'PPTEvent_PresentationOpen'
'PPTEvent_PresentationClose'
Is that necessary?

And this Module going with the code above:

```
Dim X As New ApplicationEventClass
Sub InitializePPTEvent()
Set X.PPTEvent = Application
End Sub
```

Many thanks for your help!

I posted this question about refresh with empty screen also on vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?69782-PowerPoint-vba-Event-not-fired-when-screen-is-empty and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/796398/show-or-hide-custom-group-depending-on-powerpoint.html

Answer (score 0):

You need a sub that returns the visibilitiy per each group based on the current design:

```vb
Sub getVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal)
Select Case control.Tag
    Case "MyPersonalGroup1"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateA")
    Case "MyPersonalGroup2"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateB")
    Case "MyPersonalGroup3"
        returnedVal = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Design.Name = ("TemplateC")
End Select
End Sub
```

And you have to call `RefreshRibbon` within a WindowSelectionChange-Event.
Did you implement a Application-class already? It's described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/powerpoint/how-to/use-events-with-the-application-object

Comment: Thanks alot! I'm making the add-in in TemplateA, and MyPersonalGroup1 tab immediatly appeared. I had already this for RefreshRibbon, but that doesn't work (I've just tested it):

Dim Rib As IRibbonUI
Dim MyTag As String
Sub RibbonOnLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI)
    Set Rib = ribbon
End Sub

Sub RefreshRibbon(Tag As String)
    MyTag = Tag
    If Rib Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Error, restart your presentation"
    Else
        Rib.Invalidate
    End If
End Sub

But I must make a WindowSelectionChange-Event? I don't really understand how to do that ...

Comment: Did you read the link I provided - there is described how you have to proceed ...

Comment: google for "vba powerpoint application events" - you will find some tutorials

Comment: You need to use the `IRibbonUI.Invalidate` or `IRibbonUI.InvalidateControl` methods to force Office applications call the callbacks anew. See my answer for more information.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev Thanks a lot! I added to this page what I have till now (see my answer). I'm almost there but it is still unstable. Maybe you can take a look? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't really post answers, modify your original post instead.

Comment: I changed it right away @EugeneAstafiev! I wanted to give as much information as possible, but did it the wrong way...

Answer (score 0):

The ribbon is static from its birth. The only possible dynamism is available through callbacks. In the ribbon XML you can define the `getVisible` callback which can be invoked when you need to hide or show controls.

For example, if a code writer implements the `getVisible` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the state loads, and then if the state needs to be updated, the cached state is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in place until the add-in signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached. The add-in can then force an immediate update of the UI by calling the `Refresh` method.

In the following example, starting the host application triggers the `onLoad` event procedure that then calls a procedure that creates an object representing the Ribbon UI.

```
<customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

Next, a callback procedure is defined that invalidates all of the controls on the UI and then refreshes the UI.

```
Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 
 
Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
 Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
End Sub 
 
Sub myFunction() 
 MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
End Sub
```

The `getVisible` callback has the following signature:

```
C#: bool GetVisible(IRibbonControl control)

VBA: Sub GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible)

C++: HRESULT GetVisible([in] IRibbonControl *pControl, [out, retval] VARIANT_BOOL *pvarfVisible)

Visual Basic: Function GetVisible(control As IRibbonControl) As Boolean
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

If you develop a VSTO based add-in you may find the [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2022) article helpful.